# React-Redux-Form Could not find form for "user" in the store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I'm getting this exception:

```
 Uncaught Error: Unable to create Form component. Could not find form for "user" in the store.
```

**Here's my reducers.js**

```
function initialUserState(state = {email: '', password: ''}) {
    return state;
}

const crmApp = combineReducers({
    auth,
    user: initialUserState
});

export default crmApp;
```

And **here's index.js**

```
let store = createStore(reducers);
console.log(store.getState());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Console output show that store contains "user" object:**
**Object {auth: Object, user: Object}**

```
auth:
  Object
     isAuthenticated:false
     isFetching: false
  Object
    user:
      Object
        email:""
        password:""
```

The user is basically model for login form.

Does someone have ideas how to fix that? Probably i'm putting the user model wrong in redux store?

Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add redux-form to your reducer as detailed [here](http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/docs/GettingStarted.md/). You shoudl end up with something like this.

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const crmApp = combineReducers({
    auth,
    user: initialUserState,
    form: formReducer
});
```

You also need to make sure you have attached the form correctly at the component level. You didn't post any code for your component though.

Comment: I was following this guide [link](http://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/models.html) in terms of forms. But there is nothing about formReducers and form decoration below.
`// Decorate the form component
ContactForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'contact' // a unique name for this form
})(ContactForm);`

Comment: That link is a 404

Comment: I got it working :)
Code below for combineReducers:
`const crmApp = combineReducers({
    auth,
    deep: combineForms({
        user: initialUserState
    }, 'deep')
});`

i was forgot about combineForms helper.

Comment: @spirift I believe this answer is for the wrong react redux form component.